# bootsrap sass mixins and browser prefixes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm trying to use the SASS [@transition mixin](https://github.com/jlong/sass-bootstrap/blob/master/lib/_mixins.scss#L126) in a project using bootstrap:

```
a.navbar-brand {
  @include transition(all 0.6s 0 ease);
  background: url('../images/logo-gray.png') 0 50% no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 60px;
```

The transition renders as `transition: all 0.6s 0 ease;` - there's no browser prefixing going on.

Am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: Are you sure that your mixin looks like the one? Did you include the right one:
`@mixin transition($transition...) { -webkit-transition: $transition; transition: $transition; }`

Comment: My scss file imports `bootstrap.scss`, which imports `bootstrap/mixins`, which includes Bootstrap's transition mixin(s).

Comment: UPDATE: I updated `grunt-autoprefixer` and now I'm seeing the prefixes.

Comment: @ryancito  what version are you using here ?